# Alias options in zsh

Tags: zsh, alias

When using the zsh alias command, what does the `-s` flag do (for example, lines 83-87 of [oh-my-zsh's common-alias plugin](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/common-aliases/common-aliases.plugin.zsh)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### what does the -s flag do

`alias -s ...` creates a **Suffix Alias**, which allows you to assign commands to filename suffixes.

---

#### Suffix Aliases

> Since zsh 4.2.x its possible to make a programme alias for a given
>   filename extension. That means, you can assign commands to filename
>   suffixes.
>
> `alias -s txt='less -rE'`
>
> Now every time you enter a $filename with extension .txt `less -rE $filename` is invoked.
>
> If you use `'*.txt'` then all files with that extension will be invoked
>   with the command `less` with options `-r -E`.

Source http://zshwiki.org/home/examples/aliassuffix

---

#### Examples

> Suffix aliases are supported in zsh since version 4.2.0. Some
>   examples:
>
> ```
> alias -s tex=vim
> alias -s html=w3m
> alias -s org=w3m
> ```
>
> Now pressing return-key after entering foobar.tex starts vim with
>   foobar.tex.
>
> Calling a html-file runs browser w3m.
>
> www.zsh.org and pressing enter starts w3m with argument www.zsh.org.

Source [ZSH-LOVERS(1)](http://grml.org/zsh/zsh-lovers.html)